# Boostrap dynamic div position

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i need yout help.

i've two parent div,

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
 <div class="row-fluid" id="id">
```

in these div I put other div created by an ajax call.

I created a div which will then be populated with data.
the div is:

```
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-5 space">
            <h2 style="color:#900000">###</h2>
            <p class="lead">###
            <p>
            <p style="text-align: right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>12/5/24</p>
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="">
            </div>

            <div class="caption">
                <p>Differetn lenght of data  -<<< PROBLEM IS HERE
                   text.</p>


                <a href=download="sss" class="padd">Allegato: ssss'</a>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The ajax call make 5 div 
Of these with a different length.

[image: this is now]
[image: how i want]

EDIT OF masonry
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this [masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/#initialize-with-jquery)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container masonry">
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick large"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick small"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick small"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick small"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick large"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick large"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick small"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick small"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick small"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick medium"></div>
    <div class="block masonry-brick large"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.block',

});
```

[For demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/FPpUD/)

Comment: the third div want to get up

Comment: Not now, i'm out, but it simple an ajac call, data and append with jquery in the parenti div,

Comment: But the last edit i have added the div of your post; the problem isn't i'm my div